# Silverlight graph control

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, graph

I need to include a graph editor (users should be able to place elements from a list in the graph and link them with other ones, much like an organizational chart) in my Silverlight application but have no idea how to do so. None of the controls in the SDK or the Toolkit seem to be made for such a scenario and using one of the various third party controls is not an option.
Could someone please suggest me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing seems to be a moderately complex graphical Silverlight application. I really don't see other options than either using 3rd party controls (though I'm not aware of ones that support "linking" together as you've mentioned) or implementing the whole thing yourself.

To do it yourself I'd suggest using custom controls to create the "nodes" and handle mousedown, mosemove & mouserelease events to draw and implement connections between them. Having said this I'd put this task anywhere from a man week to two man months to complete based on complexity and you're experience with Silverlight.